# AngularJs Package or Solution for saving to file

Tags: angularjs

I am relatively new AngularJS and what I am trying to do is build a simple application that has a table and at the bottom a button that will say export and take the JSON object make it .pretty() and then save to disk(download it) as a .txt file... Now I currently have already used ng-csv so I am familiar with the process but I am looking to incorporate something like that that can export .txt files and more file options as well. Also if there is just a simple way to write to disk that would be amazing as well.

Comment: There is no file access from browser window. You need a server running a programming language to write files

Comment: then how does ng-csv do it?

Comment: you can do a download or `save as` but that is user accepting and knowing what is going on. Accepting download and write to file are not the same thing

Comment: i am talking about saving to a local machine

Comment: Browser security restrictions don't give you file access (for obvious reasons). If you ran a localhost server would work though, but that assumes this is for your own use only. Otherwise there are also lots of cloud data services you can use but must be running page from a server to use those also

Comment: @charlietfl he's talking about File API and offering a download from pure JS. That is entirely possible.

Comment: @JohannesJander that's not how I interpret "write to file". OP already has download capability